# Sqlite3 Issue, Column title not accepted

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

|  | Type | Location | 2019_perc | 2020_perc | 2021_perc | 2022_perc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | County | Crawford | 1.55 | 1.85 | 1.1 | 1.1 |
| 1 | County | Deck | 0.8 | 1.76 | 3 | 2.5 |
| 2 | City | Peoria | 1.62 | 1.64 | 0.94 | 2.2 |

I have some data that's in a Dataframe with the above format. I'm accessing it using sqlite3 and using matplotlib to graph the data. I am trying to compare employee raises with the yearly CPI(one section of the bar chart with 2019 percentages for each location and the CPI that year, another for 2020, 2021, and 2022). To do so I'd like to create bins by year, so the table would look more like this:

|  | Year | Crawford | Deck | Peoria |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019 | 1.55 | 0.8 | 1.62 |
| 1 | 2020 | 1.85 | 1.76 | 1.64 |
| 2 | 2021 | 1.1 | 3 | 0.94 |
| 3 | 2022 | 1.1 | 2.5 | 2.2 |

Is there any easy way to do this using pandas queries/sqlite3?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (`df`) is your *dataframe*, here is one way to do it :

```
out = (
        df
          .drop("Type", axis=1)
          .set_index("Location")
          .pipe(lambda df_: df_.set_axis(df_.columns.str[:4], axis=1))
          .transpose()
          .reset_index(names="Year")
          .rename_axis(None, axis=1)​
      )
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   Year  Crawford  Deck  Peoria
0  2019      1.55  0.80    1.62
1  2020      1.85  1.76    1.64
2  2021      1.10  3.00    0.94
3  2022      1.10  2.50    2.20
```

Plot (with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html)):

```
out.set_index("Year").plot.bar();
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to tweak it a little bit, but it achieved exactly what I had hoped for!

Answer (score 0):

Consider [**`melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html#pandas.melt) + [**`pivot`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html#pandas.pivot):

**Data**

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = '''\
Type    Location    2019_perc   2020_perc   2021_perc   2022_perc
0   County  Crawford    1.55    1.85    1.1     1.1
1   County  Deck    0.8     1.76    3   2.5
2   City    Peoria  1.62    1.64    0.94    
'''

with StringIO(txt) as f:
   cpi_raw_df = pd.read_csv(f, sep="\s+")
```

**Reshape**

```py
cpi_df = (
    cpi_raw_df.melt(
        id_vars = ["Type", "Location"], 
        var_name = "Year",
        value_name = "perc"
    ).assign(
        Year = lambda df: df["Year"].str.replace("_perc", "")
    ).pivot(
        index = "Year",
        columns = "Location",
        values = "perc"
    )
)

print(cpi_df)
# Location  Crawford  Deck  Peoria
# Year                            
# 2019          1.55  0.80    1.62
# 2020          1.85  1.76    1.64
# 2021          1.10  3.00    0.94
# 2022          1.10  2.50     NaN
```

**Plot**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

...

sns.set()
cpi_df.plot(kind="bar", rot=0)

plt.show()
plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

[image: Plot Output]